# Returning different types from controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller, action, complextype

Is there a way to return models to the client using ajax?
In a mvc controller i'm trying to do this;

```
MyController : Controller
{
    public MyObjectType GetNew()
    {
        return new MyObjectType();
    }
}
```

This returns to the client just "AssemblName.MyObjectType".
Maybe there's some method to override but i don't know the entire framework.

Comment: Can you return a JSON object?

Comment: You're gonna need to provide some more detail if the given answers aren't working for you. If you want to consume this object in the browser, then you're going to need to serialize it to XML or JSON or some string representation of your own design, there's just *no other way.* If you want to consume this object in a View, then you'll need to stick it in the ViewBag and in Razor you can deal with the object more or less *in the normal way*

Comment: It would be nice to elaborate on the decisions you make to the type of solution you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You could serialize the object as JSON and return a [`JsonResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.jsonresult%28v=vs.118%29.aspx). At the client you can deserialize it again.

You should call the [`Json(object)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.json%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) method to serialize your object to JSON.

Answer (score 0):

As Patrick suggested you could return a JsonResult. Otherwise an ApiController will serialize for you.

```
MyController : ApiController
{
    public MyObjectType GetNew()
    {
        return new MyObjectType();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to return JsonResult and don't wanna use ApiController because it only acepts 1 parameter when posting, so wrapping parameters in a object to receive data isn't my deal.

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to do either? How do you want your client to receive the data?

Comment: You can easily pass multiple parameters in an Action.

Comment: Well, the mvc controller calls the "ToString" method when an unknown type is returned. But when it's array, the controller return only it's type.

Comment: And when you wrap it in a [Json()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.json(v=vs.118).aspx) call?

Comment: He doesn't want a JsonResult... @glhrmbhnrt - You either need to pass your type along to a view to be displayed or you need to return Json/Xml. Since you're asking about ajax, passing to a view is out of the question. So I'm left with return Json - but why don't you want to do this?